# Unable to print description text in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

AS i want to get the description text from https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-viva-shoe-ZQTSV8/DB5268-003
but print none on output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re
url ="https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-viva-shoe-ZQTSV8/DB5268-003"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

headline1 = soup.find('h3', class_ = 'epdp-headline-md headline-1')

headline = soup.find('div',class_ = 'epdp-headline-sm body-1')
print(headline1,headline)
```

Comment: if you see the [source of the page](view-source:https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-viva-shoe-ZQTSV8/DB5268-003), there is no class with either `epdp-headline-md` or `epdp-headline-sm` and that's why you are getting `None`.

Comment: `http https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-viva-shoe-ZQTSV8/DB5268-003 | grep epdp-headline` gives me no output, so it doesn't look like the data you are looking for is there. It might be dynamic content, downloaded later via JavaScript.

Comment: So how do i get that data?

Comment: #brunns is there any way to get the data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses select rather than find.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ="https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-viva-shoe-ZQTSV8/DB5268-003"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

description = soup.select('div.description-preview>p')
color = soup.select('div.description-preview>ul>li:nth-of-type(1)')
style = soup.select('div.description-preview>ul>li:nth-of-type(2)')

print(description[0].text)
print(color[0].text)
print(style[0].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# importing required libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# target URL to scrape
url = "https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-viva-shoe-ZQTSV8/DB5268-003"

# headers
headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"
    }

# send request to download the data
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

# parse the downloaded data
data = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

You need to use this class `pt6-sm prl6-sm prl0-lg` to extract the description

```
html_text = data.find('div',class_ = 'pt6-sm prl6-sm prl0-lg')
```

Returns the description.

If you wish to clean the HTML objects, you can use the below snippet

```
import re

def cleanhtml(raw_html):
  cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
  cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', raw_html)
  return cleantext

txt = cleanhtml(str(html_text))
```

```
print(txt)
```

Output:

```
Designed with every woman in mind, the mixed material upper of the Nike Air Max Viva
features a plush collar, detailed patterning and intricate stitching. The new lacing
system uses 2 separate laces constructed from heavy-duty tech chord, letting you find the
perfect fit. Mixing comfort with style, it combines Nike Air with a lifted foam heel for
and unbelievable ride that looks as good as it feels.Colour Shown: Black/Dark Citron/Green
Abyss/Plum DustStyle: DB5268-003View Product Details
```